# PHP $_SESSION sometimes working sometimes it doesn't

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, sessionid

Good day,

I have a small but not unimportant issue.
Created a SESSION class and in general it works just fine.

However for some strange reasons, once in a while it starts to quirk and it generates an individual sessionID for each different page /  folder.

*The situation is as follow.*

I am using the Session class in my own framework.
My framework uses routing based upon a directory structure.

Such as:

- http://domain.com/clients/groups/editgroup=5

I do this at the hand of a **.htaccess** file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine           on
    RewriteRule             ^$    core/    [L]

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I try to route all traffic to a file in a folder /core/index.php
 Here I load all my modules and my session class.

> **The issue**
>
> In general it runs fine. BUT on a regular base (once in a while) when
>   I log in it forwards the user from the login page to the start page.
>   There it detects that the user has not been logged in and forwards him
>   back to the login page.
>
> **So you have one domain. But multiple folders where the system generates multiple Session ID's..**

**#1 The user logs in under:**

> http://domain.com/login/
>
> 1 Session ID generated
>   2 Login check
>   3 User login data gets
>   registrated
>   4 User gets forwarded to the next page

**#2 User arrives at:**

> http://domain.com/start/
>   1 Session ID SHOULD be maintained. BUT
>   gets for some reason REgenerated
>   2 User fails to authenticate and
>   gets forwarded to the previous page

**#3 User arrives at:**

> http://domain.com/login/
>   1 Original Session ID is found
>   2 User
>   authenticates with the data stored in session and forwards to the next
>   page

**#4 User comes back at the start page and again finds another session id.. etc. etc.**

I use the following settings before starting the session:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',      432000);
///ini_set('session.cookie_path',           false); /// Disabled this option because this should be causing this issue. But to no avail unfortunately.
ini_set('session.cookie_domain',        'domain.com');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure',        false);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly',      true);

ini_set('session.gc_probability',       0);
```

I wonder where I might have made the mistake.
The session class is a lot bigger of course. But I think it would be too big to post it in whole.
If any questions about a specific part ask and I will post it.

Hope that someone can see my error.
Thanks in advance!

*At this moment I solve this by deleting all domain session cookies.
Then I load http://domain.com/login/ again and login and everything runs fine again. But in a couple of days the problem occurs again.*

The session FILE contents:

```
SessionIPaddress|s:9:"127.0.0.1";SessionuserAgent|s:72:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0";Parking_loggedin|b:1;Parking_user|s:1:"1";Parking_level|s:1:"1";
```

> **The gitHub link to the file**
>
> https://github.com/alexhakkenberg/https---github.com-alexhakkenberg-sessionclass/blob/master/session.class.php

Comment: Add a gist link of your session file if that is possible ?

Comment: @Maz What do you mean?

(* The contents of the session file?, added them. :-) *)

Comment: I meant the session calss of yours. Since it is big, just upload it as a github gist  and add the link?

Comment: With a little fiddling with the GitHub code I added my code

Answer (score 2):

### Some problems

The mass of comments makes the code not more but less readable. Without all the comments the file is only ~350 lines instead of 714. It's easier to grasp the overall intend of a shorter file. Lots of comments are also just rewording of the code, these are not even helpful. For example `return(false)` is speaking for itself and must not be annotated.

You are duplicating PHP functionality, especially concerning the cookie handling. This is done already by PHP.

You are creating a file in `WriteSession`, which does not contain the session data and is thus a bit misleading. (The session data ist actually saved by the core PHP functions.) The file only contains some data to check the session, maybe to prevent hijacking, but it is not explicitly used to prevent the hijacking. The hijacking is prevented by checking data stored in the session (right way!), so the additional file is unnecessary. (Please see that some agents switch IP while surfing your site, thus checking the full IPv4 might be annoying for those visitors.)

### Some tips

- You are mixing an abstraction layer to the session array (`__get` / `__set`) with storage code. Be sure to separate these two aspects at least in your mind or even separate them into two classes.

  - The abstraction layer should contain everything around `session_start`, e.g. hijack-prevention, destroying a session, ... and should not write / retrieve any data. It should be based solely on `$_SESSION`.
  - The storage layer should fulfill exactly one task: Write and retrieve `$_SESSION`.
- Unless you are absolutely sure what you want to achieve, just use the custom PHP functions to store / retrieve session data. If you for whatever reason want to change the way data is stored, use [appropriate php methods for that](http://php.net/session_handler). Possible use case for that is storing the session in a database, to be able to operate with the data easily.
- Recheck the documentation or a PHP session tutorial on what PHP already provides for you. Do not invent the wheel again.
- Do not care for the domain. In the real world you will likely never run into problems with tangled sessions over different domains. (Because the storage folders for the session will be set to different locations for different webroots.)
- Last time I saw them the reflection methods were meant to be only used for "special purposes". Circumventing the programmers need to just write down the variables might not be such a "special case".

Comment: In other words this comes down to... Rewrite the class.. :-#?

Comment: Since right now the storage functionality even does not work properly, it essentially boils down to "remove unnecessary things and refactor the left overs" ;) but yes, I would not leave the class as it is. Removing the domain thingy and the additional files will likely solve your problem.